# WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput strange behaviour. Can enable, but cannot disable

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, sendmessage, unity-webgl

I am experiencing very strange behaviour of WebGLInput.
I have a website with a WebGL Unity build. By default WebGL is capturing all keyboard inputs. However, I have to use input fields in my html.

So at first I disable WebGLInput and it works:

```js
private void Start()
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL 
     WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput = false;
#endif
}
```

Then using function below I send a message to unity to toggle the keyboard input. And it works at first to enable it, but it doesn't disable it!

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "#canvas") {
        this.FocusCanvas("1");
    } else {
        this.FocusCanvas("0");
    }
}.bind(this), false);
```

This is my unity code to toggle WebGLInput:

```js
public void FocusCanvas(string focus)
{
    #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
        if (focus == "0") {
            WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput = false;
        } else {
            WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput = true;
        }
    #endif
}
```

I debugged it as far as I could and I'm more than sure that method is triggered and everything is executed. But disabling captureAllKeyboardInput does not work. Have someone encountered such problem? if so, please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I found a smooth solution to that. There is no need to toggle it. I just disabled it and added tabindex="1" to canvas. Now keyboard works in input fields and on canvas when focused.